# Python get position of string and the next X lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

There's a lot of questions like this but they're all dealing with files. I'm just dealing with a string:

```
"""
Your username is: 
joe
normal
"""
```

I need to find the position of "Your username is: " and then grab the next 2 lines after it. There isn't a file.txt to work with.

Comment: Are you dealing with a multi-line string? Can you post an example of the input and output desired?

Comment: In the example, I'm looking to get line 2 and line 3 so I could have x=joe and y=normal

Comment: Multi-line string should always have 3 single or double quotes (on both ends). `"""` or `'''`. Updated the question to reflect correct multi-line usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT Ver 2:

Updated the code to reflect the new changes done to the input data

```
example ='''This is an example string
That has multiple lines
With the words Your username is:
joe
normal
It should NOT grab this line
However it should detect the next line as it has
Your username is:
jane
also_normal
Do not grab this line'''
grab = False
line_count = 0
for line in example.split('\n'):
    if grab == True and line_count < 2:
        print (line)
        line_count +=1
    elif 'Your username is:' in line:
        grab = True
        line_count = 0
    else:
        grab = False
        line_count = 0
```

The output of this will be:

```
joe
normal
jane
also_normal
```

## EDIT Ver 1:

I think you are looking for a code that can process multi line string variable and present you with an answer.

```
example ='''This is an example string
That has multiple lines
With the words Your username is: joe normal in the string
Program should grab this first line
And this second line and print
It should NOT grab this line
However it should detect the next line as it has
Your username is: joe normal
Grab this first line again
And grab this second line as well
Do not grab this line'''

grab = False
line_count = 0
for line in example.split('\n'):
    if grab == True and line_count < 2:
        print (line)
        line_count +=1
    elif 'Your username is: joe normal' in line:
        grab = True
        line_count = 0
    else:
        grab = False
        line_count = 0
```

The output of this will be:

```
Program should grab this first line
And this second line and print
Grab this first line again
And grab this second line as well
```

Comment: I think you've nailed it. Testing now my biggest problem is the string sometimes has matching lines I've just got to grab the right ones.

Comment: This works given what I asked. I should have said I wanted to disregard everything before "Your username is : "

Comment: If you need any additional changes to the code, let me know and I am happy to help you get the updated code

Comment: You have the right answer I'm just not thinking through what I'm doing. Sorry long day of failing :(. Thank you!

Comment: Long day of learning. Happy to have been part of your learning process. Feel free to reach out if you still have questions

Answer (score 1):

You could split the text by Your username is: and than detect where Your username is: and than get the next to lines
here's a code example

```
splittext = "Your username is: joe normal".split("Your username is:")
splittext.remove('')
for i in range(0, len(splittext)):
    splittext[i] = splittext[i][1:len(splittext[i])]

#returns joe normal
```

Comment: also if you don't want the for loop in there, you can instead change the split parameter to "Your username is: " I just added the space to the end

Comment: Sorry I just realized my formatting was messed up. This is a multiline string.